# upgrading pip on windows recursively download all the dependencies

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm using devpi as my private pypi server. When I was upgrading pip in an elevated command prompt, I noticed a recursive behavior which I haven't seen before, simply pip is downloading all the pips down to pip 1. What's going on?

```sh
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Looking in indexes: http://localhost:3141/packages/staging/
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (20.3.2)
Collecting pip
  Downloading http://localhost:3141/root/pypi/%2Bf/fab/098c8a1758295/pip-20.3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.5 MB ...
  Downloading http://localhost:3141/root/pypi/%2Bf/79c/1ac8a9dccbec8/pip-20.3.3.tar.gz (1.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.5 MB 6.4 MB/s
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
  Downloading http://localhost:3141/root/pypi/%2Bf/8d7/79b6a85770bc5/pip-20.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.5 MB ...
  Downloading http://localhost:3141/root/pypi/%2Bf/aa1/516c1c8f6f634/pip-20.3.2.tar.gz (1.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.5 MB 6.4 MB/s
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
  Downloading http://localhost:3141/root/pypi/%2Bf/425/e79b20939abbf/pip-20.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.5 MB 6.4 MB/s
  Downloading http://localhost:3141/root/pypi/%2Bf/43f/7d3811f05db95/pip-20.3.1.tar.gz (1.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.5 MB 6.4 MB/s
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
  Downloading http://localhost:3141/root/pypi/%2Bf/323/6fe7288d155c2/pip-20.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.5 MB ...
  Downloading http://localhost:3141/root/pypi/%2Bf/9ae/7ca6656eac22d/pip-20.3.tar.gz (1.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.5 MB ...
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
  Downloading http://localhost:3141/root/pypi/%2Bf/51f/1c7514530bd5c/pip-20.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.5 MB 6.8 MB/s
  Downloading http://localhost:3141/root/pypi/%2Bf/85c/99a857ea0fb0a/pip-20.2.4.tar.gz (1.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.5 MB 6.4 MB/s
  Installing build dependencies ... canceled
ERROR: Operation cancelled by user
```

When I ran the same command in a non-elevated prompt pip works as it should

```sh
python -m pip install pip
Looking in indexes: http://localhost:3141/packages/staging/
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (20.3.2)
```

Again it's kind of weird to recursively go and download all the dependencies. I think if I had an older pip the non-elevated prompt would throw an error cause the pip is not installed in user home directory.

```sh
python -m pip list --path "c:\python39\lib\site-packages"
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        20.3.2
setuptools 50.3.2
vboxapi    1.0
```

By ruling out devpi, it is pip for sure, again the same behavor

```sh
python -m pip install --index-url https://pypi.org/simple --upgrade --no-cache-dir pip
```

Ok reported [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9402)

Comment: Have you checked _pip_'s bug tracker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is a [bug](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9284) which is triggered by `-U/--upgrade` flag on `pip 20.3.2`. To solve the issue I installed pip 20.3.3 by providing an exact version.

```sh
python -m pip install 'pip==20.3.3'
Looking in indexes: http://localhost:3141/packages/staging/
Collecting pip==20.3.3
  Downloading http://localhost:3141/root/pypi/%2Bf/fab/098c8a1758295/pip-20.3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.5 MB 6.4 MB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 20.3.2
    Uninstalling pip-20.3.2:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-20.3.2
Successfully installed pip-20.3.3
```

And seems it is solved for now

```sh
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Looking in indexes: http://localhost:3141/packages/staging/
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (20.3.3)
```